# Creating a script that organizes drums

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, find, osx

I would like to create a script that looks in a specified directory, takes in a keyword (i.e. 'kick' , 'snare') and copies all related .wav files into a separate directory.

I would then like for it to group the .wav files into sub directories containing 128 .wav files per sub directory for as many as it needs.

The folder I am searching through is /Users/bot/Documents/_Sound\ Library

So far I've come up with:

find /Users/bot/Documents/_Sound\ Library -iname 'kick?.wav'

I put the ? for the folders that may be called 'kickz' or 'kicks'

Comment: What does "group them by 128" mean?  Also please provide a sample of what your starting directories look like and how you would like the results to look.

Comment: Meaning after 128 files are scanned through they are packaged into a directory by themselves.  Hopefully being called the keyword and a numerical value.  The starting directory : /Users/bot/Documents/_Sound\ Library

Comment: Also using the cp function so the initial directory stays intact

Comment: So you want to have a command that does something like:  `findandmove kick /Users/bot/Documents/output` and it would create folders under `output` like `kick01` `kick02` `kick03` `kick04` each with 128 files with `kick` in the title copied in them from the source directory?

Comment: Yes.  So the contents in the directory with the keyword KICK would just be put into folders elsewhere.  I want to keep original file unaffected.  Was thinking this might work:  find /Users/bot/Documents/_Sound\ Library -iname 'kick?' -exec cp {} Newdir

Comment: So how are the files actually called? Your pattern `kick?` matches `kick1` or `kick9`, but not `kick10` or `kick.ogg`. Is that desired? It's also important to know whether there can be multiple files with the same name, so the files also need to be renamed when collected in one directory. If not, please separate the task into first collecting the files and then reorganize them. FInally you write capital *MOVE* in your question, but you seem want to copy. **In short: edit your question to contain all relevant information that one needs to help you.**

Comment: The files should keep their original name.  The only thing that needs to be named are the new directories housing the already existing files.  Preferably the code won't take into account duplicate files if that is possible.  So yes the first task would be locating all directories with keyword "kick" or "kicks" or "kickz".

Comment: And yes since we would like to keep the original directory unaffected I think a copy command would be necessary.  Beastmanh was able to write a code below that kind of does what was asked except the ending folders doesn't populate with the files it scanned.  I hope this clarifies.

Comment: And also need to filter files so it only accepts .wav files in the end but checks the directories called kick anything

Answer (score 1):

I threw together a quick bash script to hopefully do what you're asking for.  Save it to a file like `sort.sh` and then execute it like `./sort.sh kick` or `./sort.sh snare` (file space search term).  It will find files based on the value you passed in, then create numbered directories like `kick_1` and `kick_2` etc.  Plus it will leave an index file in each directory with all file names, if you like.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i numFiles
declare -i numDirs
mkdir ./temp

## Find files and copy to ./temp directory
find -E  /Users/bot/Documents/_Sound\ Library -regex ".*($1).*" -exec cp {} ./temp/ \;

## Get total number of files found and divide by 128 (+1 to allow for the final directory)
numFiles=`ls ./temp | wc -l`
numDirs=$numFiles/128+1

## All the file moving and directory naming
for i in $(seq 1 $numDirs); do
        mkdir $1_$i;
        ls ./temp/ |head -128 > $1_$i/$1_$i.index
                for x in `cat $1_$i/$1_$i.index`; do mv ./temp/$x $1_$i; done

        ## Uncomment if you want to remove the index file
        #rm $1_$i/$1_$i.index
done

## Remove temp directory
rm -rf ./temp
```

Comment: I'm gonna test this out.  I have little experience creating scripts but gonna see how it goes!  Thanks!!

Comment: Question.  Where does it save the copies?  In the same directory?

Comment: Also is it searching just directories or files as well?  It would have to search the directories only take the .wav files

Comment: It seemed to work but the last directories had the index with the file names but no files.  Could there be a reason for this error?

Comment: Are you running it on a mac?

Comment: Yes I am on a Mac

Comment: Should it be different because I'm running on MacOS?

Comment: In each index it also is showing the same samples

Comment: I really don't see how that could be happening :/  Apologies